# Rename a file with a batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, timestamp

How do you rename a file to include the datetime using the windows command line?

Comment: What do you mean by with date time?  Do you want to update the timestamp?

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to rename "file" to "file.20081030" or similar.

Comment: or do you mean append the datetime to the filename?

Comment: I do think it is programming related. There are more batch file / command shell question, this one is just a bit vague.

Comment: I attempted to clarify the question. Shashigupta, if I got it wrong let me know, and please try to be a little more clear in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a similar question:

[How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [StampMe.cmd](http://www.ss64.com/nt/stampme.txt) at http://www.ss64.com/nt/syntax.html.